# locale aware string comparision

Tags: php, localization, string-comparison, sorting

I´m using `strcmp` in combination with `usort` in order to sort an array of country names. Currently, the sort order is:

```
Belgien
Frankreich
Italien
Luxemburg
Niederlande
Spanien
United Kingdom
Österreich
```

Which is correct, apart from the position of `Österreich`. It should be between `Niederlande` and `Spanien`.

I also tried `strnatcmp` and `strcoll` (with `setlocale`), but the sort order was not the way I wanted it. The results are not from a mysql db, so sorting via a mysql query is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, meanwhile I am working at another company on another project, but faced recently the same problem. What finally worked was installing the [intl extension](http://php.net/intl) for PHP.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

And then using:

```
$arr = array(
"Belgien",
"Frankreich",
"Italien",
"Luxemburg",
"Niederlande",
"United Kingdom",
"Österreich",
"Spanien",
"Ásdf",
);

$coll = collator_create('de_DE');
$coll->sort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Returned the results in the expected order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ásdf
    [1] => Belgien
    [2] => Frankreich
    [3] => Italien
    [4] => Luxemburg
    [5] => Niederlande
    [6] => Österreich
    [7] => Spanien
    [8] => United Kingdom
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (assumes script is in UTF-8):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
"Belgien",
"Frankreich",
"Italien",
"Luxemburg",
"Niederlande",
"United Kingdom",
"Österreich",
"Spanien",
"Ásdf",
);

setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "pt_PT.UTF8");
usort($arr, 'strcoll');
print_r($arr);
```

gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ásdf
    [1] => Belgien
    [2] => Frankreich
    [3] => Italien
    [4] => Luxemburg
    [5] => Niederlande
    [6] => Österreich
    [7] => Spanien
    [8] => United Kingdom
)
```

However, this is painful; it requires the locale to be installed. `locale -a` gives you the installed locales, e.g. in my machine it gives me:

```
C
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
POSIX
pt_PT.utf8
```

Comment: I tried your code and setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "de_DE.UTF8");, but it wont sort me the array in the correct order, although I verified that the locale is available.

Comment: @Max Perhaps your script is not in UTF-8. Try de_DE.iso88591